# Python requests if response contains string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Okay so I'm testing pythons request module with beautifulsoup4 & wanted to create an if statement & an else statement, my current code is -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

for page_no in range(1,2365):

source = requests.get('http://example.com/page={}'.format(page_no)).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

profile = soup.find('div', {'class': 'title'})

for content in profile.find_all('a'):

    print(content.text.encode("utf-8"))
```

this will currently go through the given amount of pages and scraped all a tag contents within a div class title, but I want to create some failsafes..

so

```
if "Example text" in source:

proceed with script example - //profile = soup.find('div', {'class': 'title'})
                             //for content in profile.find_all('a'):
                            //    print(content.text.encode("utf-8"))
else:

    print "response does not contain Example text"
```

now I understand this is clearly not how you produce such results but I'm just giving you a example of how i would like things to be.

Comment: What is the problem with the solution you proposed?

Comment: @bla it just doesn't seem to be working, it's responding else print everytime.

Comment: Can you provide the actual url you are using or maybe some sample html so I can test locally?

Comment: there is no actual url, its just for educational purposes, you could use any page and create the same process.

Comment: Your literal string is probably not in the `source` string. Perhaps you misplaced a space or a comma? I did a very small test here: https://gist.github.com/nathan-cruz77/b1a5368305df46d3624ad92fc6e7061c

Comment: If it is about educational purpose, the thing you should care about first is `indentation`. Your code is horribly indented.